# Windows 7 command line: request MS Security update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I am trying to eliminate the SMBv1 vulnerability from a Windows 7 box.  I do keep the machine patched with Windows updates, however, I would like to install the proper update because I was unable to confirm it was installed.

One can query which MS updates have been applied with:

```
wmic qfe
```

Results were piped into a file and a search for update 4013389 was negative.  If this is not the correct technique to determine if the vulnerability patched please state this.

If it is a valid technique, is there a command to specifically to retrieve and install security update 4013389?

Comment: Why don't you just download the kb from the windows catalog?  Why are you making it harder on yourself?

Comment: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012215

Comment: I marked it as answer because it applies to you too. Check [win7 history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009469/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-history) and look if you have the last KB update installed.

Comment: I mean duplicate. Here you see that the way to check for a KB is crap and [only a check for the file version is correct](https://superuser.com/a/1209007/174557)