# How to tell which cumulative update a KB is in or if I have it installed?

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

I am trying to confirm that a specific KB is installed on my system (as I've found information suggesting that it fixes an issue I'm seeing). Running `wmic qfe` doesn't list this particular KB (suggesting that it's not installed), but windows update tells me it's completely up to date (suggesting that it must be installed).

I understand that updates for Windows Server 2016 are cumulative and that the KB I'm looking for may have been rolled into a newer update - therefore its fixes could be installed but not explicitly listed by name.

So, is there a way to find out if the KB I'm looking for is in one of the updates I have installed?

---

Edit: the hotfix I'm looking for is KB3192366; the updates I have installed are:

- KB3176936
- KB3192137
- KB3199209
- KB3199986
- KB4013418
- KB4023834
- KB4025339

Comment: Related: [How can I query my system via command line to see if a KB patch is installed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/263847/how-can-i-query-my-system-via-command-line-to-see-if-a-kb-patch-is-installed)

Comment: @andselisk yes, that's how I got the list of installed updates listed in the bullets above.

Comment: KB3192366 is Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016: September 26, 2016 so if you have a later cumulative update installed you are good to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a specific Windows security update is installed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1208741/how-to-check-if-a-specific-windows-security-update-is-installed)

Comment: don't check for a [KB number, check for a file version](https://superuser.com/a/1209007/174557)